# What does "grabbed scoreboard slot" mean when running Apache in debug mode?

Tags: apache-2.2, debug

I am running Apache 2.2 in debug mode, and I see that the error_log constantly shows the following:

```
[Tue Dec 19 10:02:06 2017] [debug] proxy_util.c(1909): proxy: grabbed 
scoreboard slot 0 in child 4528 
for worker ajp://192.168.70.35:8009/auctions
[Tue Dec 19 10:02:06 2017] [debug] proxy_util.c(2025): proxy: initialized 
single connection worker 0 in child 4528 for (192.168.70.35)
[Tue Dec 19 10:02:06 2017] [debug] proxy_util.c(1909): proxy: grabbed 
scoreboard slot 1 in child 4528 for worker ajp://192.168.70.35:8009/opi
[Tue Dec 19 10:02:06 2017] [debug] proxy_util.c(2025): proxy: initialized 
single connection worker 1 in child 4528 for (192.168.70.35)
[Tue Dec 19 10:02:06 2017] [debug] proxy_util.c(1909): proxy: grabbed 
scoreboard slot 2 in child 4528 for worker ajp://192.168.70.35:8009/opa
```

What does grabbed scoreboard slot N mean? What does all this mean in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not sure if I was the right person to answer this here, since I am sure there are dozens if not hundreds of devs who can explain this much better than I, but let me try to do this...

Briefly, the scoreboard is a **mechanism** that httpd uses **so parent process can "talk" to child processes and assign load**.

It is, briefly again, the whole thing you see in represented in mod_status, or as the httpd official docs say, "representation of all the running processes and the status of their worker threads".

What you see in your paste there are purely **debugging messages**, you should not have those unless you are trying to debug an issue, but you are asking about messages specifically and not about an issue. If you are just asking because you see those in your error log, but you don't have an issue. Set "Loglevel warn" or search "LogLevel debug" in your config and change it to warn, because those messages are for lower level/layer debugging.